# Store Graphics in Local when browser refresh

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Using ArcGIS Javascript API, I am adding different graphics to the map. Later I will save them in a server. If I forgot to save, or due to some reason, the page is refreshed before saving, I lose all the graphics. My requirement is to replace the graphics to that particular session.
Is there any possible way to save the graphics?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do, is to save the graphics on the [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) of the client browser.

Note that local storage or DOM storage, is an HTML5 feature, and older [IE browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) do not support it.

For a deeper understanding, read this article from [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Here are two ESRI JS samples which might be useful:

1. [Store bookmarks client side](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/exp_bookmarks_stored_client_side.html)
2. [Local storage - experimental](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/exp_localstorage.html)